# Prompt user for amount of time and object falls and then calculate velocity using functions

Tags: c++, function

I have written the code with absolute no error codes. However whenever i try to the run the program i get a build failed error. All my definitions are the same and i dont see any indication that anything is different. Can someone help?

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    const double GRAVITATION_CONSTANT = 9.8;

    int getFallingTime();

    int fallingDistance(int fallTime);

    void displayResults(int fallTime, int fallDistance);

    int main()
    {
        int fallTime, int fallDistance;

        fallTime = getFallingTime();

        fallDistance = fallingDistance(fallTime);

        displayResults(fallTime, fallDistance);

        cout << "End program - ";

        return 0;
    }


    int getFallingTime()
    {
        int fallingTime;

        cout << "Ener seconds the object falls: ";

        cin >> fallingTime;

        while (fallingTime <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Enter seconds the object falls: ";
            cin >> fallingTime;
        }
        return fallingTime;
    }

    int fallingDistance(int fallTime)
    {
        int fallDistance;

        fallDistance = 0.5 * pow(fallTime, 2) * GRAVITATION_CONSTANT;

        return fallDistance;
    }

    void displayResults(int fallTime, int fallDistance)
    {
        cout << "In " << fallTime << " seconds, the object falls " << fallDistance << " meters.";
    }
```

Comment: What does "build failed error" mean? What is the *exact* error message the compiler is giving you?

Comment: Also, `int fallTime, int fallDistance;` looks wrong. That should probably be `int fallTime, fallDistance;`

Comment: Are you missing `#include <math.h>`?

Comment: did the two steps above! compiled correctly! why do you think it didnt compile correctly using the second int? I thought it didnt matter. @Kai @scohe001?

Comment: You can do `int X, Y;` but the compiler is unhappy about having the type re-declared after a comma.